# How to add BLK theme to an angular CLI project

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I've created an Angular project with CLI, I want to use [BLK theme](https://demos.creative-tim.com/blk-design-system-angular/#/documentation/navbar) by Creative Tim in this project.

But the only option in the by [Creative Tim](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/blk-design-system-angular?_ga=2.13126135.1303796670.1596272303-1086801589.1596272303) is to download an existing project and work on top of that.

I really don't want to do that, Is it possible to add this theme to my CLI project?

Tried `npm i blk-design-system-angular` But that didn't work.

Comment: Did you use angular theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried running the `npm i blk-design-system-angular` and did `ng-serve` and it does have one problem in one of the `_images.scss` file.
[image]

after adding the `{` in the `_images.scss` file it run smoothly. Below is the example I copy paste from their website and put it in the `app.component.html` to test run it. https://demos.creative-tim.com/blk-design-system-angular/#/documentation/grid
[image]

and don't forget to add your reference in the `styles:` section in your `angular.json` as per their Quick Start [here.](https://demos.creative-tim.com/blk-design-system-angular/#/documentation/quickstart)

```
   "node_modules/blk-design-system-angular/src/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css",
   "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
   "node_modules/blk-design-system-angular/src/assets/scss/blk-design-system.scss",
   "node_modules/blk-design-system-angular/src/assets/demo/demo.css"
```

However, it still does download the whole project into the `node/modules` after `npm install`, but you can still work with the class from on a blank page.